# Магазин и front-end разработчик

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Что требуется от front-end разработчика при разработки магазина. Интересует вопросы:

1. когда допустим 200 единиц товара. front-end разработчик должен ведь насколько я понял сделать 1 пример страницы, а дальше все делает backend разработчик?
2. Добавление в корзину.
3. Отзывы или комментарии.

Comment: а не слипнется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 единиц товара прилетают в маленьком json, типа

```
{ 
  [
    {id:1, "n":"пылесос", "price":200}, 
    {id:2, "n":"яхта", "price":99999}
  ]
}
```

твоя задача все это обработать и выдать правильный js  для картиночек-ссылочек, эффектов и т.д.

с другой стороны, бэкэнд может прислать тебе полный html-ответ, тогда тебе гораздо легче жить.

все, что не должно быть персистентным в базе данных или может быть безопасно обработано на стороне пользователя, может прилететь фронтэндеру.

1) думай в категориях клиент/сервер

2) все зависит от архитектуры проекта